# Notification not showing up when I close the app

Tags: java, android, notifications

So I made some code that makes the app show up at the time specified. It works well enough when the app is open on the screen, but when it is closed, it doesn't work at all. I need help making it show up.

Code for MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initChannels(this);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

    // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
    // 20 minutes.
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Code for MyReceiver.java which extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
public MyReceiver() {

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentService.class);
    context.startService(intent1);
}
```

Code for MyNewIntentService which extends IntentService:

```
private static final int notificationId = 4242;

public MyNewIntentService() {
    super("MyNewIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //NOTIFICATION CREATION
    // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("This is the title")
            .setContentText("This is the body of the notification.")
            .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And I added this in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".MyNewIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

I know there's a lot of text in this question and I apologize for that, but I think that'll make it easier for you to help me or see what the problem is.

Comment: have you tried `WorkManager` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#java

Comment: @AshutoshSagar I have checked out the WorkManager page and I don't really get it. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Try out this page for a simple example https://www.androidauthority.com/schedule-background-tasks-jetpacks-workmanager-874189/

Answer (score 0):

try this

- firebase notification are two types:

  **data message:** when your app background/foreground/killed your push notification is worked

  **display message:** when your app foreground push notification works

Handle push notification these stages **background/foreground/killed**

it depends your **json response** make sure your json response like this:

```
{
 "to": "registration_ids",
 "data": {
 "key": "value",
 "key": "value",
 "key": "value",
 "key": "value"
 }
 }
```

this is my code when your app **background/foreground/killed** it works fine

```
  @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "remoteMessage......" + remoteMessage.getData());
    try {
        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
        Log.e(TAG, object.toString());
        body = object.getString("not_id");
        dataa = object.getString("data");
        title = object.getString("not_type");
        type = object.getString("type");
        Sender = object.getString("Sender");
        SenderProfileUrl = object.getString("SenderProfileUrl");

    wakeUpScreen();
    addNotification(remoteMessage.getData());

}

/* when your phone is locked screen wakeup method*/
private void wakeUpScreen() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

    Log.e("screen on......", "" + isScreenOn);
    if (isScreenOn == false) {
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyLock");
        wl.acquire(10000);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyCpuLock");
        wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
    }
}

/*Add notification method use for add icon and title*/
private void addNotification(Map<String, String> data) {
    int icon = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ?R.drawable.logo_app: R.drawable.logo_app;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon)
                    //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logout_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(data.get("title") + "")
                    .setChannelId("channel-01")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(uri)
                    .setContentText(data.get("body") + "");

    Notification notification = new Notification();

    Log.e(TAG, "titlee" + data.get("title"));

    // Cancel the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    if (sound)
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    if (vibration)
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    builder.setDefaults(notification.defaults);

     }
    }
```

when i click notification bar goto the particular screen using type like this:

```
    /*notification send with type calling */
            if (data.get("not_type").equals("calling")) {
                if (data.get("type").equals("name")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ttt--" + type);
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, CallingActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("notification_room_id", body);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("data", dataa);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("calling", "calling");

                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                    builder.setSound(uri);
                    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

                    // Add as notification
                    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        CharSequence name = "Hello";// The user-visible name of the channel.
                        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel-01", name, importance);
                        manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                    }
                    manager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), builder.build());

                }
```

this is my manifest add notification class and token class

```
 <service android:name=".notification.NotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".notification.TokenService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".notification.NLService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

i hope it helps you